# adding and removing elements dynamically within nested loops vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I Want to create a dynamic list of time ranges within list of date ranges and give each generated ul and li a specific class/id.

This is how far I got. It gives an error that newElement is null! I saw some answers with generating rows, but you can't give them a specific class/ids.

I like it this way better since you have control over each ul and li.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('date');
var add  = document.getElementById('add');

//adding a new element to the list
addDate.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var newElement = document.createElement('LI');
  list.appendChild(newElement);
  var i; 
  for (i=1;i<10; i++){
    newElement.innerHTML = "NEW Date Frame<span class='btn'>X</span><ul id='timeframe-"+[i]+"'></ul><button id='addTime'>Add a Time Frame</button>";
    
    var addTime= document.getElementById('addTime');
    var timeframe = document.getElementById('timeframe');
  
    addTime.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var newElement = document.createElement('LI');
      timeframe.appendChild(newElement);
      newElement.innerHTML= "NEW Time Frame<button class='btn'>X</button>";
    });
  }
});

//removing
list.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
    // List item found!  Output the ID!  
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
ul span {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="date">
    <li class="element">Date Frame</li>       
  </ul>
  <button id="addDate">Add a Date Frame</button>
</div>
```

Comment: your lists do not respect the html syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are creating multiple timeframes but you were selecting only one:

`var timeframe = document.getElementById('timeframe');`

What you need to do is selecting specific timeframe each loop:

`var timeframe = document.getElementById('timeframe-' +[i]);`

```js
var list = document.getElementById('date');
var add = document.getElementById('add');

//adding a new element to the list
addDate.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var newElement = document.createElement('LI');
  list.appendChild(newElement);
  var i; 
  for (i=1;i<10; i++){
  newElement.innerHTML= "NEW Date Frame<span class='btn'>X</span><ul id='timeframe-"+[i]+"'></ul><button id='addTime'>Add a Time Frame</button>";
  
  
  var addTime= document.getElementById('addTime');
  var timeframe = document.getElementById('timeframe-' +[i]);
 
  addTime.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var newElement = document.createElement('LI');
  timeframe.appendChild(newElement);
  newElement.innerHTML= "NEW Time Frame<button class='btn'>X</button>";

});
}
});


//removing
list.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
  // List item found!  Output the ID!  
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
 }
});
```

```css
ul span {
cursor: pointer;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <ul id="date">
        <li class="element">Date Frame</li>       
      </ul>
    <button id="addDate">Add a Date Frame</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to thoroughly explain your answer rather than just dumping code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry im new here. I edited 1 line of code: 
var timeframe = document.getElementById('timeframe-' +[i]);

Comment: @PiotrSzulc you can edit your answer and add that explanation in it :)

Comment: If you only changed one line, no need to provide all of it again.

Comment: @PiotrSzulc Thank you for your answer, but if you try your code, add the second date frame and then go back add time frame to the first one, it adds 10 time frames, which is not right. it should add 1 time frame.